# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' date field

Tags: python, excel, postgresql

I searched for this error and was able to find some information. I am importing Excel into postgreSQL and below is my script. I know the error is regarding how Python is handling a blank field. The script None if not has functioned fine for other tables I have imported and it also works fine for the Traffic field for this table but for some odd reason throws out an error for Week_Ending date field. I am new to Python and StackOverflow so if you decide to down vote my question please tell me why.

```
import psycopg2
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("consolidateddata.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Builder_Traffic")
database = psycopg2.connect (database = "", user="", password="", host="", port="")
cursor = database.cursor()
delete = """Drop table if exists "Python".buildertraffic"""
print (delete)
mydata = cursor.execute(delete)
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE "Python".buildertraffic
   (Builder_Name varchar(55),   
Traffic integer,
Week_Ending date,
Project_ID integer
   );''')
print "Table created successfully"
query = """INSERT INTO "Python".buildertraffic (Builder_Name, Traffic, Week_Ending, Project_ID)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
Builder_Name = sheet.cell(r,0).value
Traffic = None if not sheet.cell(r,1).value else sheet.cell(r,1).value
Week_Ending = None if not sheet.cell(r,2).value else xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(r,2).value,book.datemode)
Project_ID = sheet.cell(r,3).value
# Assign values from each row
values = (Builder_Name, Traffic, Week_Ending, Project_ID)
# Execute sql query
cursor.execute(query, values)
cursor.close()

database.commit()

database.close()

print ""
print "All Done! Bye, for now."
print ""
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)
print "I just imported Excel into postgreSQL"
```

When run, this fails with the stack frame

```
Week_Ending = None if not sheet.cell(r,2).value else  xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(r,2).value,book.datemode)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xldate.py", line 123, in xldate_as_datetime
days = int(xldate)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Print out the value to see if its what you think it is. For instance, `print(repr(sheet.cell(r,2).value))`.

Comment: Hi tdelaney thanks.       print(repr(xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(r,2).value,book.datemode))) it shows the dates when I run the script.

Comment: Print the things you plan to pass to `xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime` before you make the call. The way you are doing it, it will just raise the exception again.

Comment: When I run the script as you have suggested tdelaney it results in numbers like 42575.0, 42589.0 etc.... and then it throws out the same error about invalid literal.